# unimplemented function msvcr120.dll when launching dbg debugger on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dll, wine, dbg

I am installing dbg debugger on ubuntu. After I launch the dbg debugger with wine command. I met this problem:

***Unhandled exception: unimplemented function msvcr120.dll.?_Id@_CurrentScheduler@details@Concurrency@@SAIXZ called in 64-bit code (0x000000007b44f037).***

I checked the directory, msvcr120.dll is there. However, I don't know why it cannot be implemented. I tried both 32 bit and 64 bit version of dbg. They both have the similar problems.

Any answer and comment is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your best bet is to update wine to the latest release. This is currently wine-2.17.

Comment: ***However, I don't know why it cannot be implemented.*** wine has not implement 100% of the windows API. There is some missing functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

- Launch `winecfg`
- Go to `'Libraries'`
- In the `'New override for library'` field search `msvcr120` and press `Add`

Comment: the option to set is, (native,builtin) for msvcr120